# Problems with transforming maven project into eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I perform action mvn eclipse:eclipse to convert from maven project to eclipse, but it occurs an error: Cannot execute mojo: eclipse. It requires a project with an existing pom.xml, but the build is not using one.

Before it I executed command mvn archetype:generate and chose android-quickstart

It created project with pom.xml inside. can anyone help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you ran mvn eclipse:eclipse in the wrong directory. After you run mvn archetype:generate and choose android-quickstart you should see a new directory (possibly called android-quickstart), change to this new directory and then run mvn eclipse:eclipse i.e. you must run it in the same directory as your pom.xml as Jeremy said

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow too but I think you should accept an answer (Jeremy's or mine) see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

In order to convert a maven project to an eclipse project, your project must *first be* a maven project, which requires a pom.xml to exist.